# Calculating Proportions for Baseball-Related Query

Tags: sql

Here are my two tables:

**BIO** - contains player biographical information with the following columns

- i. PLAYER_ID
- ii. PLAYER_NAME
- iii. DATE_OF_BIRTH
- iv. TEAM_NAME

**PITCHES** - contains batter and pitcher statistics by pitch with the following columns

- i. GAME_DATE (formatted YYYY-MM-DD, e.g. 2016-01-01)
- ii. BATTER_PLAYER_ID
- iii. PITCHER_PLAYER_ID
- iv. PITCHER_THROW_SIDE (L/R)
- v. BATTER_HAND (L/R)
- vi. PITCH_TYPE (Changeup, Curveball, Cutter, 4-seam fastball, Knuckleball, 2-Seam
- Fastball, Slider, Splitter)
- vii. PITCH_CALL (Ball, CatcherInterference, FoulBall, HitByPitch, InPlay, StrikeCalled,
- StrikeSwinging)
- viii. IN_ZONE (YES/NO)

I want a query that returns the names of players with an in-zone or out-of-zone swinging strike rate of greater than 15% for fastballs for the 2016-2017 seasons, combined. I also want team name, pitcher handedness, and to include cutters and sinkers as fastballs.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT b.PLAYER_NAME, b.TEAM_NAME, p.PITCHER_THROW_SIDE
FROM BIO AS b INNER JOIN PITCHES  AS p
ON b.PLAYER_ID = p.PITCHER_PLAYER_ID
WHERE p.PITCH_TYPE = '4-seam fastball' OR p.PITCH_TYPE = '2-Seam' OR p.PITCH_TYPE = 'Cutter'
AND p.GAME_DATE BETWEEN 2016-01-01 AND 2017-12-31
GROUP BY b.PLAYER_ID
HAVING (Count(IN_ZONE)) ....
```

I think this is the right idea... but I'm a bit lost now as to how I can include the 15% in-zone/out-of-zone rates.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: @Jake . . . Sample data and an explanation of how the rate is calculated would make it possible to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you calculate  in-zone or out-of-zone swinging strike rate of greater than 15%?
if NR_YES/total

```
HAVING sum(case when IN_ZONE='YES' then 1 else 0)/count(*)>0.15
```

If Nr_Yes/Nr_NO

```
HAVING sum(case when IN_ZONE='YES' then 1 else 0)/count(*)>3/17
```

Note that 3/17 is 15/85. Since there is only the possibility of yes and no

Also note that with the sum of 0s and 1s I am actually simulating a

```
count(*) where IN_ZONE='YES'
```